# Woocommerce thank you page has Elementor template reference in URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have a website that is built using Elementor and Woocommerce.

After a customer purchases a product they are redirected to

```
/?elementor_library=elementor-products-archive-1713%2Forder-received%2F41942%2F&key=wc_order_U4yRGC3hrCF3E&utm_nooverride=1
```

I believe it should just go to:

```
/order-recieved/{ordernumber}&key=wc_order_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Does anyone know why the Elementor reference is being added and why the characters are shown as : %2F41942%

Changing the `order-recieved` endpoint and checking for any redirection settings

Comment: It seems like a misconfiguration within [Elementor](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/14578). The second question is just `/41942/` with HTML entities encoded. Check this out for more information on the latter issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325676/why-wp-encodes-unicode-utf8-containing-urls-any-drawbacks-of-unicode-url